# how to achieve useEffect like hook in angular?

Tags: angular, hook

how can i use useEffect like hook in angular?

in react we do this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(`/users?id=${post?.userId}`);
      setUser(res.data);
    };
    fetchUser();
}, [post?.userId]);
```

as we can see this hook will only run when user-id changes, now i want to achieve this same functionality in angular.

in my current code(angular):

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const res = this.postService.getAllPosts();
    this.postService.setPosts(res);
}
```

i want ngOnInit to run again only when user-id changes.

Comment: use the `ngOnChanges` lifecycle method

Comment: can you elaborate? i used ngOnChange but it didn't work.

Comment: @hawks ngOnChanges would be corresponding to useEffects where dependencies are inputs. But an effect can have any dependency.

Answer (score 2):

ngOnInit will run only once in your application, after the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook.

I'm not sure if I understood your question, you want to 'listen' to a class property change and trigger a method?

If you want to accomplish this, you can use a set method to a class property to trigger a method every time it receives a new value. Something like:

```
  export class AppComponent {
      set foo(userId: string) {
        // Do something here
      }
  }
```

You could also use ngDoCheck lifecycle hook, this will be triggered every time a data change in your component happens, although invoking this method multiple times can make your application slower.

Comment: I wanted to say that, like we pass dependency in useEffect in square brackets [var] it will only run when page is loaded or var changes.                 How can I achieve this same functionality like only run ngOnInit only first time page loaded or var changes.